# Xcode showing unknown characters

Tags: iphone, crash

Please anybody help me with this,

my xcode project showing this charachters when i restarted my pc, any solutions are welcomed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you changed the encoding of the characters to an unknown encoding

To solve it,

- make sure that the class.m file is saved in UTF-8 format, to save it to utf-8, open it with any editor (for example textedit) and save it to UTF-8 format
- make sure that the encoding in xcode is set to UTF-8, go to preferences->text editing
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for Instant Help,I tried this way but no changes in charachters

Comment: did you try saving the file again in utf fromat?

Comment: yes i tried by duplicating this file and then saving  it with utf encoding 8

Comment: can you somehow send a section to the file to me?

Comment: yes i can send you some of lines from the code will it be ok?

Comment: ﬂ˝≥ƒWg≥ª¬∫1ùÍÇ>w&˜⁄F„Ut=?ˆh‘>x7≈g·WâgmK‚k¯)¨¶Òı‡ä{q¥øoë”k≠ËÌ∆R‹‰ì¿áÅ˛,¸@¯qm>◊ˇ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12796/discussion-between-anand-and-omar-abdelhafith)

Answer (score 0):

May be your project is connected with svn or other secure server, and unfortunately your svn stop working and at that time you save your data on svn that's why this was happen. now no way to recover this data but definitely you get that before saved data or backup which was taken by you.